# How to manage the HttpClient instance in a class library

Tags: c#, singleton, dotnet-httpclient

I'm writing a .Net Core class library that is a wrapper around a REST web service. I'm using HttpClient which [should be instantiated as a singleton](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

The big question I have now is how should I manage this HttpClient instance? Should it be the role of my class library, or of the calling code that would pass the instance to my class library.

I started with the first solution, creating a singleton instance this way:

```
public class DemoClient : IDemoClient
{
    private static readonly HttpClient HttpClient;

    static DemoClient()
    {
        HttpClient = new HttpClient();
    }

    public DemoClient(Uri baseUrl)
    {
        HttpClient.BaseAddress = baseUrl;
    }
}
```

I use the static constructor to instantiate the singleton instance and set the baseUrl in the "standard" constructor.

There's a few things I don't like about this approach. First, if the user of my class library creates a second instance of the class, setting the `baseUrl` to something else, it will break completely, first because once a query has been made, setting the `BaseAddress` throws an exception and secondly because even if you could, it would not be possible for each instance to have a different `BaseAddress`.

This means that either I force the user to create a singleton of my class which means that he wouldn't be able to create two instances for two different REST endpoint or I forget about making the `HttpClient` instance singleton but this might end up being a bad idea with the risk of wasting sockets.

The second solution would mean I'd simply leave the instantiation of the `HttpClient` to the user of my library, and ask him to pass it to my constructor. It would definitely simplify the management (at least for me :)) but it feels like leaking implementation details.

I might in the future change and use a different approach than `HttpClient` and this shouldn't have any impact of the user of my library. Moreover, it asks the user of the library to actually know how to use the `HttpClient` (and how to use it correctly), which doesn't feel "right" as well.

Is there another option I haven't thought about? This issue of having the `HttpClient` instance a singleton is quite annoying...

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary<string,HttpClient>` where the keys are the base URLs?

Comment: I wouldnt limit the user like that. While HttpClient should be reused as much as possible, there might be cases where you only do one request every once in a blue moon. In such a situation a Singleton would not really make sense. I would keep lifetime in hands of user.

Comment: @Mats391 you mean the lifetime of my class or of the `HttpClient`? It's true that an option could be to simply instantiate (non statically) the `HttpClient` inside my class, implement the IDisposable and tell the users of my class that it's probably a good idea to use my class in the same way as `HttpClient`, like a singleton if they do a lot of queries.

@Damien_The_Unbeliever: interesting option indeed, this way I can have multiple instance with different base URL with keeping the HttpClient static.

Comment: @Gimly Yep, thats what I do with a similar wrapper around a `HttpClient`.

Comment: @Gimly BaseUrl will be ignored if absolute URL is used for any http method. Ideally, an application uses single host to connect to for all api calls, and for rest, it can always use absolute url to connect outside business domain.

Comment: @AkashKava That's not the issue I'm facing in that case. The issue is that the user of my library might want to connect to two different servers offering the same REST API. Therefore, using the singleton `HttpClient` this is not possible (except using Damien's option with ConcurrentDictionary).